# How do I create and save a group of contacts in Skype?

Tags: skype, contacts

How can I create and save a group of contacts in Skype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my windows, I can do the following :  (5.1.0.112)

`Contacts > Categories > Create new category`

Don't you have this menu?

#### Edit: (from comments discussion)

To create group of people I can do : select multiple contact (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>) then r-click and "New Group Conversation.

Comment: That's about calling a group of people. The asker (and me too) wants a grouping feature.. like MSN, Pidgin, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to linux skype.
Go to contact groups -> New Contact group.

thn go to each person to whom you want to add, right click and just add to group...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help : [The next big step - say hello to group video calling](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2010/05/group_video_calling.html).