# How can I create a group of contacts in Skype?

Tags: mac, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create and save group in skype is possible? if yes,how?](https://superuser.com/questions/223372/create-and-save-group-in-skype-is-possible-if-yes-how)

- Mac OS X 10.6.7
- Skype 5.1.0.914

I can see my groups which was created earlier, but after I updated from Skype 5.0 to 5.1, I've lost ability to create new groups.