# How can I create a group of contacts in Skype?

Tags: mac, skype, contacts

I can see my groups which was created earlier, but after I updated from Skype 5.0 to 5.1, I've lost ability to create new groups.

- Mac OS X 10.6.7
- Skype 5.1.0.914

This question is not duplicate of

> [How do I create and save a group of contacts in Skype?](https://superuser.com/questions/223372)"

because there is no such a menu item here:

[image: image fromhttp://emberapp.com/antonio7/images/skype]

Comment: On the Windows version (5.1.0.112) there's a "Create Group" button at the bottom of the contacts pane, next to the "Add a contact" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skype 5.1 for Mac

A contact group is created when you tag the first person you want in a group. The group name will appear in the contact group bar at the top of Skype.

To create a new contact group:

1. Sign in to Skype.
2. In your contact list, find a person you want in the group. You can type their name into the Search field in the top right of the screen or, go to the sidebar and click Contacts, then in the contact group bar, click Skype. You may have to click >> (arrows) to see all your contact groups.
3. Right-click the contact and select Add to Contact Group > New Group.
4. In the window that appears, enter a group name, and then click Add.

   The new group appears in the contact group bar.

Tip: You can change the order that the group names appear in the contact group bar. Just click and drag the group name to a new position.

[Reference.](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10870/How-do-I-manage-my-contacts-in-Skype-for-Mac?fromSearchFirstPage=false#CreateGroup)

Answer (score 3):

In Skype 5.4.0.1771 for Mac (10.7.2) you cannot create groups in the old way. In this version and, I suspect, all versions from 5.1 onwards groups are now "tags"!

So right click on a contact and you should see "Tag...".

[image]

Click it and there are your groups and the ability to add more. Crazy how this is hidden away – but there you go. I too was getting very frustrated with this. And Skype still has yet to update their main manual.

Answer (score 1):

Name the tag or group.  Double click on contact you wish to add and double click contact again to get profile.  You will see the option 'tags' and tick the box. You will now have a group of contacts with the same tag, and therefore in a group

Answer (score 1):

And in 5.8 the groups are called Lists, so right-click and select "Add to list..."